Can I charge LIFEPO4 batteries with my boat motor alternator?
I have a Mercury 250 V8 with an alternator. It is currently wired to charge my two AGM/Flooded cell starting batteries with a VSR. I want to add 2 LIFEPO4 100Ah batteries in parallel to give me 200AH for my electronics. Can this be done safely?
Is it better to set them up separately to charge from the charger?

I'm amazed at the range of the answers. No, you can't do it safely based on the information you've provided. Each of the three  answers to follow have errors/incorrect information or the answer is too generic to be trusted. Also note that a lithium chemistry battery will live longer if charged below the maximum and stored at fifty percent state of charge.

Ok gents, I appreciate the quick responses and you sharing your expertise. what I have decided is to keep the 2 AGM batteries with the VSR connected to the motor as usual. this will keep them charged as I run about. I am installing a separate bank of 2 lithium 100AH in parallel as the house feed to power all the non-essential electronics. Teh lithium batteries will charge from an independent lithium charger/ solar charger. I asked Mercury about this too and their spec is 12 AGM for the motor. Thanks again to all for your input.

Sure you can do it safely. LFP chemistry is the only lithium chemistry compatible with lead acid. Today, you can buy drop-in replacements for Automotive and Marine batteries. There are no modifications. The batteries have a built-in BMS and thermal fuse. Modern Automotive and Marine charging systems charge at 14.2 volts and float at 13.8 volts, a perfect match for a 4S LFP battery.
Thousands of boats, RVs, and more trucks and cars than you can count use 12-volt Lithium batteries. Every box and automotive store sells them. I have them in all my 12-volt systems.


Google for "DC-to-DC battery charger." That's a generic name for products that are used in Recreational Vehicles (RVs) to charge the "house" battery from the (towing) vehicle's electrical system.
Advantages include;

The house battery can be a different chemistry from the engine starting battery (chargers for LiFePO4 are common).

The house electrical system is isolated from the vehicle electrical system. You can leave the fridge on all night, and not worry about whether you'll be able to start the engine in the morning.

The charging rate is limited by the charger, which is good for your battery, and good for your alternator.



In theory, yes, because Li-ion and lead acid use a CCCV charging profile.  However:

Most alternators are not current limited, which is fine for lead acid (it has a high resistance so it limits the current), but is hell on Li-ion batteries. Surprisingly, it's even worse on the alternator. Many have reported burned alternators after they switched from lead acid to Li-ion batteries

The top voltage of the alternator is poorly regulated and may be too high for a Li-ion battery that consists of 4 LFP (LiFePO4) cells in series. If possible, reduce the top voltage to 13.6 V or lower. That's 3.4 V per cell (assuming the battery is balanced).

LFP cells degrade over time if maintained at the top voltage (unlike lead acid batteries). They prefer to have the charging turned off when full.


TL;DR: Yes, you can do it, but don't expect a long life from a LFP Li-ion battery that replaces a lead acid battery.
